# how to merge the background of uint8 image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, image-segmentation, roi

[image]

I am trying to do lung extraction from CT images. I would like to remove the background and keep only the lungs (the yellow color background must change to blue-ish color and lungs must have unique color). How can I do that?

Comment: first you need to learn about matplotlib and what "colormaps" are. then, if you can explain why your plot is yellow and dark violet, _and_ you can explain how to change that with **only** changes to matplotlib function calls, _then_ this question may be worth another look

Comment: You can use opencv `cv2.connectedComponents` to separate all 5 blobs of yellow pixels. Then you have to use heuristics to isolate the correct blobs. For instance, blobs that touch the sides of the image should be removed.